# Making lwuit app non-touch, easy steps?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, nokia

We already have a lwuit app fully functional and are now trying to make it support non-touch devices easily. Is there any quick steps to make it support it? Any code snippets or examples would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally it "just works", if you have specific questions you should refine them to what doesn't work for you.

Make sure you have styles for the selected UIID of specific components otherwise they would be hard to distinguish.